# IBM DB Sanity tester not working

Tags: python, import, sqlalchemy, db2

I'm trying to connect to DB2 database using sql alchemy. for this i'm using ibm_db_sa dialect.

I've installed the following things,

1. sqlalchemy
2. IBM Data Server Driver Package
3. ibm_db_sa

now when i ran the IBM_DB SA adapter sanity test from their example i'm getting following error.

```
C:\Users\HemantR>python Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> import ibm_db_sa.ibm_db_sa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ibm_db_sa
>>>
```

[image: screenshot of my machine setup]

I'm not able to understand what is the problem. I'v tried renaming "ibm_db_sa-0.3.0-py2.7.egg" to "ibm_db_sa"

I've installed the ibm_db_sa by three different combination and each time I'm getting the same error.

1. easy_install ibm_db_sa (only)
2. easy_install ibm_db-2.0.4.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg  (only)
3. when both are there.

The above screenshot is for the case of 3rd method

Comment: Check your `sys.path` and make sure that `ibm_db-2.0.4.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg` is listed there (it's a folder that *contains* the module). If it isn't, append it to `sys.path` (as absolute path) and check if the import still doesn't work.

Comment: by sys.path you mean PATH enviornment vairable. I've added the path as you asked but that didn't resolve the issue,however, i'm not sure how can adding this location to path variable will solve this issue. It is the problem with python setting that it is not able to import this module or with the way i've installed the module which installed in different manner than needed. Can you please explain that?

Comment: I meant `sys.path`: It is a **python** variable. Do this: `import sys; print sys.path`. If the above mentioned folder is not listed, you need to append it (find the full path to it first): `sys.path.append(r"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ibm_db-2.0.4.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg")` or similar. Python is not finding your import and that means it does not know where to look. The problem with ".egg" **folders** is that python will not look *into* them, thus you need to add it to the path, so python searches it.

Comment: I'm able to see the package in sys.path - 
['C:\\EclipseWorkspaces\\test', 'C:\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_2.8.2.2013090511\\pysrc', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-1.1.6-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sqlalchemy-0.8.3dev-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\paramiko-1.12.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\ecdsa-0.8-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\ibm_db-2.0.4.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\EclipseWorkspaces\\test', 'C:\\eclipse\\plugins\\org.python.pydev_2.8.2.2013090511\\pysrc', ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check ibm_db_sa is installed correctly then you need to issue following command

```
import ibm_db_sa
```

else it is not necessary to import ibm_db_sa, you can issue following command directly to connect to DB2

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://db2inst1:secret@host.name.com:50000/pydev')
```

For more info you can go through http://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/wiki/README